# SBT Scoverage: Ignore value assignment

Tags: scala, scoverage

I would like to ignore variable assignments in my project, for example something like this:

```
val someString = "123"
```

Will be considered as untested by scoverage, I could mark the line explicitly using comments:

```
// $COVERAGE-OFF$
val someString = "123"
// $COVERAGE-ON$
```

This is kinda hard at this point since the project is quite big and I don't really think comments should be used for this purpose.